# Recorrer JSON usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estimada comunidad, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="texto1"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://apinow.urbano.com.sv/api/integrations/v1/geofences');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'G72lrsdWG3meqJUhdDdr7ysU4qr5QH3ASQmSWhedrZH3hUGInnwVjNPN8T3z');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', '(application/json)');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (let country of Object.keys(obj)) {
    var capital = obj[country];
    var meses = capital[0].geometry;
    console.log(capital[0].geometry);
}
  }
};

request.send();
    </script>
</html>
```

El cual me deveulve en pantalla el siguiente arreglo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien todo va encaminado a que necesito acceder a coordinates en la posicion 0 y luego que me devuelva todas las coordenadas contenidas en el, y si no es posible acceder a las posiciones [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7PB1.png),[2], etc. Agradeceria que me puedan ayudar con esto pues no tengo mucha experiencia en el tema.

Saludos.

Comment: La variable `ejemplo1.coordinates` es un Array de Array's, eso quiere decir que para acceder a los elementos de cualquier Array contenido en el Array `coordinates` debes usar doble corchete, por ejemplo: `let [longitud, latitud] = ejemplo1.coordinates[0][0];` esto almacena en `latitud` y `longitud` los valores correspondientes al primer Array de tu Array `coordinates`. Saludos

Comment: Aun no lo puedo acceder, este es el error lanzado por el navegador "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coordinates')
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange"

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo ya Funcional

```js
    let ejemplo = {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
            [
                [-89.1986, 13.6921],
                [-89.1980, 13.6914],
                [-89.1983, 13.6908],
            ]
        ]
    }

    //Accedemos de la siguiente manera:

    for(let i = 0; i < ejemplo.coordinates[0].length; i++) {
        console.log(ejemplo.coordinates[0][i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola estoy agregando en tu for la funcionalidad para que puedas leer los coordinantes:

```
for (let country of Object.keys(obj)) {
        var capital = obj[country];
        let ejemplo1 = capital[0].geometry;
        console.log(ejemplo1);
        console.log(ejemplo1.coordinantes);
        let coordinantes = ejemplo1.coordinantes;
        for(let i=0;i< coordinantes.length;i++){
            console.log(coordinantes[i]);
            let coordenadas = coordinantes[i];
            console.log("coordenada 1:" + coordenadas[0]);
            console.log("coordenada 2:" + coordenadas[1]);
        }
    }
```

Espero te ayude saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder a coordinates crea `var capital` fuera del `for of`.
`var coordinates = capital[0].geometry.coordinates[0];`obtiene el array de arrays y puedes trabajar con el con un `foreach`

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var capital;
    for (let country of Object.keys(obj)) {
      capital = obj[country];
    }
    var coordinates = capital[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
      console.log(coordinates[i]);
    }
  }
};
```